# How to derive the Louis's formula

Tags: integration

I am trying to show that $$-\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta^{2}} \log L(\theta \mid \mathbf{x})=-\int_{z} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta^{2}} \log L(\theta \mid \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z}) k(\mathbf{z} \mid \mathbf{x}, \theta)-\operatorname{var}_{\theta_{0}}\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log L(\theta \mid \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z})\right\}$$ however I get sucked at the middle of the prove.

\begin{aligned} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta^{2}} \int_z\log (L(\theta \mid x)) &=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\log L(\theta \mid x, z)) k(z \mid x, \theta) \cdot d z \\ &=\int_{z} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \theta^{2}} \log L(\theta \mid x, z) k(z \mid x, \theta) \cdot d z+2\int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\log L(\theta \mid x, t)) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(k(z \mid x, \theta)) d z\\
&+\int\log L(\theta|x,z)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}k(z|x,\theta)dz\\
&=E(\log(\theta|x,z))+2\int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\log L(\theta \mid x, t)) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(k(z \mid x, \theta)) d z\\
&+\int\log L(\theta|x,z)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}k(z|x,\theta)dz
\end{aligned}

Howeve, I don't know how to show that $$2\int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(\log L(\theta \mid x, t)) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(k(z \mid x, \theta)) d z+\int\log L(\theta|x,z)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}k(z|x,\theta)dz=\operatorname{var}_{\theta_{0}}\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log L(\theta \mid \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{z})\right\}$$
Could someone please give some hints?

---

This is the equation I encountered in my Statistical Computing class introducing estimating error term of the EM algorithm, the

$L(\theta|x)$ is the log-likelihood function of the incomplete data, $L(\theta|x,z)$ is the log-likelihood of the complete data, and $k(z|x,\theta)$ is the condition distribution.

Comment: What is $L$ in your post?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I have updated my question